# Syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error when running a simple method that takes in a proper noun string and returns the string properly capitalized.

```
def format_name(str)
    parts = str.split
    arr = []
    parts.map do |part|
      if part[0].upcase
      else part[1..-1].downcase
      arr << part
      end
    end
 return arr.join(" ")
end
```

Test cases: 
puts format_name("chase WILSON") # => "Chase Wilson"
puts format_name("brian CrAwFoRd scoTT") # => "Brian Crawford Scott"

Comment: Please post the full error message including the stack trace and the line number. Follow up question will be: Post the file to which the error message is pointing and mark the line number the error message is telling...

Comment: After running the code again, it does not generate an error message. In fact, it produces no output. Any suggestions why it's blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility that the above code returns a blank output is because your `arr` is `nil` or `blank`. And the reason your `arr` is blank(yes it is blank in your case) because of this line of code:

```
if part[0].upcase
```

in which the statement would always return `true`, because with every iteration it would check if the first element of the `part` string can be `upcase`d or not, which is `true`.

Hence, your `else` block never gets executed, even if this got executed this would have returned the same string as the input because you are just putting the plain `part` into the array `arr` without any formatting done.

There are some ways you can get the above code working. I'll put two cases:

```
# one where your map method could work
def format_name(str)
  parts = str.split
  arr = []
  arr = parts.map do |part|
    part.capitalize
  end
  return arr.join(" ")
end


# one where your loop code logic works
def format_name(str)
  parts = str.split
  arr = []
  parts.map do |part|
    arr << "#{part[0].upcase}#{part[1..-1].downcase}"
  end
  return arr.join(" ")
end
```

There are numerous other ways this could work. I'll also put the one I prefer if I am using just plain ruby:

```
def format_name(str)
  str.split(' ').map(&:capitalize)
end
```

You could also read more about the Open Classes concept to put this into the `String` class of `ruby`

Also, checkout `camelize` method if you're using `rails`.